# EJB project error: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, jboss, ejb, wildfly

I made EJB project in NetBeans 8.2 with wildfly 10.1.

I created two projects for this: EJBComponent (LibrarySessionBean.java, LibrarySessionBeanRemote.java) and EjbTester (EJBTester.java)

Error when i'm trying to run EJBTester.java:

```
run:
sty 18, 2017 3:13:55 PM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO version 3.4.0.Final
sty 18, 2017 3:13:55 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.4.0.Final
sty 18, 2017 3:13:55 PM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 4.0.21.Final
sty 18, 2017 3:13:56 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.VersionReceiver handleMessage
INFO: EJBCLIENT000017: Received server version 2 and marshalling strategies [river]
sty 18, 2017 3:13:56 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingConnectionEJBReceiver associate
INFO: EJBCLIENT000013: Successful version handshake completed for receiver context EJBReceiverContext{clientContext=org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext@527740a2, receiver=Remoting connection EJB receiver [connection=Remoting connection <5fc52344> on endpoint "config-based-naming-client-endpoint" <13a5fe33>,channel=jboss.ejb,nodename=lenovo-g580]} on channel Channel ID 8f1e528b (outbound) of Remoting connection 3701eaf6 to localhost/127.0.0.1:8080 of endpoint "config-based-naming-client-endpoint" <13a5fe33>
ejb:/EJBComponent//LibrarySessionBean!com.ejb.stateless.LibrarySessionBeanRemote -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.ejb:.EJBComponent."LibrarySessionBean!com.ejb.stateless.LibrarySessionBeanRemote"
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: ejb:/EJBComponent//LibrarySessionBean!com.ejb.stateless.LibrarySessionBeanRemote -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.ejb:.EJBComponent."LibrarySessionBean!com.ejb.stateless.LibrarySessionBeanRemote"
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:106)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:207)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:184)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1.handleServerMessage(Protocol.java:127)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingServerV1$MessageReciever$1.run(RemoteNamingServerV1.java:73)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

My code:

LibrarySessionBean.java

```
package com.ejb.stateless;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
@Remote(LibrarySessionBeanRemote.class)
public class LibrarySessionBean implements LibrarySessionBeanRemote {

    List<String> bookShelf;    

    public LibrarySessionBean(){
       bookShelf = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void addBook(String bookName) {
        bookShelf.add(bookName);
    }    

    @Override
    public List<String> getBooks() {
        return bookShelf;
    }
}
```

LibrarySessionBeanRemote.java

```
package com.ejb.stateless;

import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface LibrarySessionBeanRemote {

    void addBook(String bookName);

    List getBooks();

}
```

Client app maked in different project.

EJBTester.java

```
package com.ejb.test;

import com.ejb.stateless.LibrarySessionBean;
import com.ejb.stateless.LibrarySessionBeanRemote;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class EJBTester {

   BufferedReader brConsoleReader = null; 
   Properties props;
   InitialContext ctx;

   final String appName = "";
   final String moduleName = "EJBComponent";
   final String distinctName = "";
   final String beanName = LibrarySessionBean.class.getSimpleName();
   final String viewClassName = LibrarySessionBeanRemote.class.getName();

   {
        props = new Properties();
        props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,   org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.class.getName());

        props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://localhost:8080"); //http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080
//        props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "testuser");
//        props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "test");
        props.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);

    try {
        ctx = new InitialContext(props);
    } catch (NamingException ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

      brConsoleReader = 
      new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      EJBTester ejbTester = new EJBTester();

      ejbTester.testStatelessEjb();
   }
   private void showGUI(){
      System.out.println("**********************");
      System.out.println("Welcome to Book Store");
      System.out.println("**********************");
      System.out.print("Options \n1. Add Book\n2. Exit \nEnter Choice: ");
   }

   private void testStatelessEjb(){


      try {
         int choice = 1; 
         LibrarySessionBeanRemote libraryBean = 
         (LibrarySessionBeanRemote)ctx.lookup("ejb:" + appName + "/" + moduleName + "/" + distinctName + "/" + beanName + "!" + viewClassName);

         while (choice != 2) {
            String bookName;
            showGUI();
            String strChoice = brConsoleReader.readLine();
            choice = Integer.parseInt(strChoice);

            if (choice == 1) {
               System.out.print("Enter book name: ");
               bookName = brConsoleReader.readLine();                    
               libraryBean.addBook(bookName);        

            }else if (choice == 2) {
               break;
            }
         }

         List<String> booksList = libraryBean.getBooks();
         System.out.println("Book(s) entered so far: " + booksList.size());

         for (int i = 0; i < booksList.size(); ++i) {
         System.out.println((i+1)+". " + booksList.get(i));
         }

         LibrarySessionBeanRemote libraryBean1 = 
         (LibrarySessionBeanRemote)ctx.lookup("ejb:" + appName + "/" + moduleName + "/" + distinctName + "/" + beanName + "!" + viewClassName);

         List<String> booksList1 = libraryBean1.getBooks();
         System.out.println(
         "***Using second lookup to get library stateless object***");
         System.out.println(
         "Book(s) entered so far: " + booksList1.size());

         for (int i = 0; i < booksList1.size(); ++i) {
            System.out.println((i+1)+". " + booksList1.get(i));
         }

      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
         e.printStackTrace();

      }finally {

         try {

            if(brConsoleReader !=null){
               brConsoleReader.close();
            }
         } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
         }
      }
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code to match what's explained here: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI

Check whether "jboss-ejb-client.jar" is available in the your client classpath?

Comment: I read this site but still stuck with my example.
In my client project i have in classpath: jboss-cli-client.jar, jboss-client.jar (they are from wildfly) and EJBComponent.jar

Comment: Do you have any traces on the server side ?